# Ubuntu no longer asks if I want to delete .trash-1000 upon removal of removal media

Tags: trash

Upon removing any removable media, Ubuntu doesn't ask if I want to remove the trash folder to free up space. It used to show a dialogue which prompted me to delete the folder. How can I get this functionality back?

Comment: I have never seem this prompt myself, could it only come up if the USB is near full? You can delete the .trash-1000 file manually, just press `Alt+H` to show the hidden files in the USB and then you will be able to see the trash file and delete it.  (Not quite a true answer to your question so it's posted as a comment.)